# Parsing list arguments to steps in Python's Behave BDD

Tags: python, pycharm, bdd

Can I use predefined data types in "parse" module for parsing list arguments by "cfparse"?

I'm using behave 1.2.6.dev0 in PyCharm 2017.2. The .feature is:

```
Scenario Outline:

Given Drone flies <directions> for <distances> meters
Then it will be <distance> meters from launchpad
Examples:
  | directions | distances | distance |
  |North, West | 3, 4      | 5        |
```

The steps file is

```
from behave import *
use_step_matcher("cfparse")

@given("Drone flies {directions+} for {distances:n+} meters")
def step_impl(context, directions, distances):
pass 

@then("it will be {distance:n} meters from launchpad")
def step_impl(context, distance):
pass
```

Here {directions+} should be a list of strings, with "+" implying 1..* cardinality. The 'n'  is the pre-defined number type in "parse module".  (From https://pythonhosted.org/behave/tutorial.html  and https://jenisys.github.io/behave.example/datatype/builtin_types.html)

I get the error:
    ...
    File ".../python3.6/site-packages/parse.py", line 614, in extract_format
    raise ValueError('format spec %r not recognised' % type)
    ValueError: format spec 'n+' not recognised

Is there a way to reuse the predefined types? Or do I need to write user-defined types for List of strings, List of ints, etc?

Comment: The plus operator in ``{directions+}`` is wrong. The plus operator for cardinality many is only allowed if you specify a type, like ``{directions:w+}`` (many words separated by comma). Otherwise, define a type first. Details and concrete examples are described in http://behave.github.io/behave.example/datatype/cardinality_one_or_more.html (and following) and https://github.com/jenisys/parse_type

Comment: If it does not work with built-in datatypes, you need to specify user-types which should not be a problem. The implementation was intended for user-types because it needs access to the regex.